# Estoy intentando maximizar horizontalmente una ventana y a la hora de ejecutar el programa la ventana aparece igual que como estaba

Tags: java-swing

```
class marco extends JFrame {
  public marco() {
    setSize(500,300);
    setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_HORIZ);
    setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Este es el código que tengo.

Answer (score 0):

muevele el width en la funcion  `setSize`

```
setSize(W,H)
```

W= Width
H= Height